# how to find value from optgroup then find value option add attribute selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to find value from optgroup then find value option add attribute selected
Html

```
    <select id="venue">
    <option value="0">select</option>
        <optgroup label="New England">
            <option value="1">&nbsp;NH</option>
            <option value="2">&nbsp;ME</option>
            <option value="3">&nbsp;VT</option>
            <option value="4">&nbsp;MA</option>   
            <option value="4">&nbsp;CT</option>   
            <option value="4">&nbsp;RI</option>
</optgroup>   
        <optgroup label="International">
            <option value="100">Canada</option>
            <option value="100">Texas</option>
            <option value="100">Mexico</option>
</optgroup>
    </select>
```

**Jquery**
    var Id="1"

```
  $('#venue').find('optgroup').each(function () {
        $(this).find('option').each(function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        if ($this.val() == Id) {
                            $this.attr('selected', 'selected');
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
             });
```

we want find value 1 and Which option has 1 value Add Attribute selected

Answer (score 1):

why loop when you can go directly if you have the data to point it?

```
$("#venue")
   .find("optgroup[label='New England']")
   .find("option[value=" + Id + "]")
   .attr("selected", true)
```

Comment: but actually we find option which have value 1 and  get option set attribute selected

Comment: if you want to get the option via its value without narrowing down the possibilities (you can see your example: multiple options with the same value). you can directly select it using this only `$("#venue").find("option[value=" + Id + "]").attr("selected", true)`

Comment: my concern is that, you are going through loop when you're not supposed to do it, since you have the needed data to select the element you want.